# jquery plugin to show the whole website in small (like sausage.js)

Tags: jquery, plugins, web, preview

some time ago i found a plugin that shows the whole website as a small version next to the original one and also marks the current position of the page there, too.

of course i didn't bookmark it and now i need exactly this plugin for a project :(

i searched alot and the only similar plugin i found was [sausage.js](http://christophercliff.github.com/sausage/), but thats not exactly what i need.

has anybody an idea how this plugin is called?

--

update: i found a plugin that exactly do what i needed: [mini-map](http://samcroft.co.uk/mini-map/)!
it's not that i had found some time ago but it looks also very good.